# Merge two Data frame python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two Data-Frame having exactly same column names.

Example:
df1

```
PassengerId  Age   Sex  Survived
 23           43    M       0
 26           34    F       1
```

df2

```
PassengerId  Age   Sex  Survived
 12           24    M       0
 13           26    F       1
```

What I want to do is merge these Data-frame into single Data-Frame that will look like this:

df:

```
PassengerId  Age   Sex  Survived
 23           43    M      0
 26           34    F      1
 12           24    M      0
 13           26    F      1
```

Any suggestion how can I do this?

Thank You

Comment: Just [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) and search before asking!

Answer (score 1):

In pandas:

if you want to keep values from *both* dataframes use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

if you want to *merge* two dataframes by distinct criteria (e.g inner, right, left) see [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

will merge the two `dataframes` to one.